# Django JSONField does not save 0 value

Tags: python, django, postgresql, model, django-jsonfield

I have a JSONField in my model, when I try to save 0 as value in json in django admin page, it saves value as null. How can I save zero as value?
Django version: 2.1.7

Django admin page:

[image]

my JSONField:

```
lecturer_scores = JSONField(
        verbose_name=_("Lecturer Score"),
        validators=[validate_lecturer_score],
        default=dict,
        blank=True
    )
```

My input:

```
{
"score 1": 0,
"score 2": 5
}
```

it saves like:

```
{
"score 1": null,
"score 2": 5
}
```

Validator:

```
from django.core.validators import validate_integer
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_lecturer_score(value):
    for k, v in value.items():
        if v:
            validate_integer(v)
    for value in value.values():
        if value:
            if value < 0 or value > 100:
                raise ValidationError(_("Lecturer score for user's participance rate calculation should be between 0 and 100."))
```

Comment: what is your `validate_lecturer_score` i reproduced your code except the validator. And the field saved as `0` not `null`.

Comment: what is your database? i can't reproduce it using postgres https://imgur.com/a/ETBZVHF

Comment: my database is PostgreSQL

Comment: in the input you replace the `null` with zero and after save, in the database you get `null`? can you add `print` inside your validator?

Comment: in validator i get 0 but in db it saves null

Comment: magic!) django signals or database triggers, maybe save method?

Comment: Do you have anywhere loops like two shown above with `if value:` inside?

Comment: @BearBrown issue was in my signal, I call a property method and set the values. I check if value is empty set it as null. something like this ```lecturer_scores[key] = self.lecturer_scores.get(key) or None```

Comment: please write the answer for other who will search the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

issue was in my signal, I call a property method and set the values. I check if value is empty set it as null. something like this `lecturer_scores[key] = self.lecturer_scores.get(key) or None`